# Encrypt separate root and home partitions

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub, luks

So I am trying to install Arch Linux with separate root and home partitions (also swap and boot ofc). Basically I've partitioned them, I've mounted them, and I've encrypted `/` and `/home` (using `cryptsetup luksFormat`). It looks like this under `lsblk`:

(sorry, cannot copy the text from the virtual machine at this stage)
[image]

Now I am trying to achieve the following things:

- I want to decrypt all the partitions at system startup, without having to type the passphrase for each one (I've made them identical by the way)
- I want to configure GRUB for the encrypted partitions, but so far I've only seen configurations with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=/dev/sdXY:cryptroot"` and I have two of them, so I don't really know what should I put here (maybe only `/` one?)

So for now I am stuck at the point when I want to run `mkinitcpio` and `grub-install/grub-mkconfig` but I can't since I probably won't be able to boot my system without a proper GRUB configuration.

Do you guys know how would I achieve this? The second one is more important, since there are docs on the first issue, just wanted to put it there for a one-liner advice I guess, it's the second one I've been scratching my head about for the last two hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the Unix & Linux StackExchange!

The job of the initramfs file generated by `mkinitcpio` is only to unlock and mount the root filesystem; mounting other filesystems like `/home` will happen a bit later in the boot process, after the root filesystem is unlocked and mounted. GRUB does not need to know anything about the `/home` filesystem.

The `cryptdevice` option supplies information for the scripts within the initramfs file for unlocking the encryption of the root filesystem. This allows you to easily change the name of the device that is assumed to hold the encrypted root filesystem, should your system configuration change later. For robustness in the face of unexpected changes to system configuration, you might actually want to use the `UUID=<UUID_of_sda3>` syntax in place of the device name.

So you could configure the encryption of `/home` use a key file stored somewhere within the root filesystem. Since the key file would be located within an encrypted partition, it will be protected when the system is not running. And after the root filesystem is accessible, `/etc/crypttab` will be able to refer to that file, and so the encryption of the `/home` filesystem can be unlocked automatically.

According to [the crypttab paragraph of the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#crypttab), the entry for your `/home` filesystem in `/etc/crypttab` might look like this:

```
crypthome /dev/sda4 /etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/crypthome.key
```

You might want to use the `UUID=<UUID of sda4>` here also instead of the device name.

You would ensure `/etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/` is accessible by root only (`chmod 700`), and write the passphrase for the `/home` filesystem into the `crypthome.key` file. If an intruder could read this, it means the intruder has effectively root access, so they could e.g. replace your `cryptsetup` command with one that emails any passphrases to the intruder, no matter whether they are typed or read from a file, so at that point you will have bigger worries anyway.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly - grub config only has to have an entry for root partition. And as for unlocking with only one passphrase - I would use `/etc/crypttab`. And by the way, about this passphrase - does it have to be plaintext? I mean it's no problem for me, but is storing a plaintext passphrase on a disk secure? (even on encrypted root partition in a directory with root-only privileges)

Comment: And by the way, you mentioned `UUID=<UUID of the /home filesystem>` is it the UUID of `/dev/sda4` or the UUID of `crypthome`? (they differ, obviously - `/dev/sda4` is a `crypto_LUKS` partition, `crypthome` is `ext4`)

Comment: And by the way, after editing all of those above - what about `/etc/fstab`? Do I need to change UUIDs there to for example `/dev/mapper/cryptroot` and `/dev/mapper/crypthome`?

Comment: Sorry, edited: I meant in the crypttab and GRUB option you should have the UUID of the corresponding disk device, as the filesystem UUIDs are not readable at that point because of the encryption. And for `fstab`, you want the UUIDs of `cryptroot` and `crypthome`, as you need the actual filesystem for mounting, not the encrypted container. See my edit for the security worry.

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer is very helpful. So summing up: I edit `/etc/crypttab` (adding only `crypthome    UUID    key_path`), I edit GRUB config, I edit `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` to include `encrypt` in hooks` + I actually create the key file with a passphrase. By doing all the above the result will be: I only have to put in one password (to the `/` partition) when booting up, and this will automatically decrypt by `/home` partition

Comment: Yes (assuming you meant the `crypttab` line as `crypthome UUID=12345... key_path`). And the exact pathname `/etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/crypthome.key` may be significant for the latest versions of `systemd`, so you might want to use exactly that path. At boot, the system should ask you the passphrase for `/`, unlock it, and then using systemd autodetection and/or information in `/etc/crypttab`, automatically unlock `/home` using the key file, and mount it as per `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for a thorough explanation!